# The Things I Can Do

Tags: riddle

I can be unpleasant

I can be ugly

I can work hard

I can be persistent

I can be a tool

I can be hot

I can be the stars

But most of all

I can be your friend

What am I?

Comment: Would appreciate feedback from whoever voted to close this... clearly it couldn't have been too broad if it was guessed on the first go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What am I?

> You are a dog!

I can be unpleasant

> dogs without potty training and smelly dogs can be unpleasant

I can be ugly

> Bulldog

I can work hard

> sled dog

I can be persistent

> blood hound on the trail

I can be a tool

> dogs can be a hunting tool or a digging tool

I can be hot

> hot dogs taste good

I can be the stars

> Taco Bell Dog, Air Bud and of course my favorite Tillman the skateboarding dog!

But most of all I can be your friend

> dog is mans best friend!

Comment: This was my first answer in the puzzling stack. I answered quickly but will return to edit my answer once I figure out how to use formatting, post clues etc.

Comment: Fantastic first answer, very quick. However the first few reasons and the one about stars is incorrect...
What gave it away?

Comment: well I read all the clues together so its hard to say which one gave it away. mans best friend and hots dogs came to my mind quickly:) I just changed my stars answer

Comment: Dogs is correct, but there are a few more interpretations than our furry companions. I just wanted to make sure some clues weren't much easier than others, so thanks for your feedback.

Comment: thanks. I will have to think more about non furry companion answers! This stack is fun